# SVD. why U and V have to be both orthonormal matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, svd

I'm looking for the SVD factorization
$A = U D V'$ starting from the set of equations
$A  u  = v d$ and $A'  v  = u d$. Where u and v are vectors from the A and A' spaces and d the singular value.

Follows that $A u u'= v d u' $. If we just consider u as being an orthonormal matrix we get $A = U D V'$. My question is, what im doing wrong (in literature they say we need both u and v have to be orthonormal).

[ then why we need to apply a gram-schmit to the eigen vectors of v ]
Thanks

Comment: It isn't needed, requiring that the matrices are unitary is a different statement, a stronger one. So why not?

Comment: acording to wiki Formally, the singular value decomposition of an m×n real or complex matrix M is a factorization of the form

    \mathbf{M} = \mathbf{U} \boldsymbol{\Sigma} \mathbf{V}^*

where U is a m×m real or complex unitary matrix, Σ is an m×n rectangular diagonal matrix with nonnegative real numbers on the diagonal, and V* (the conjugate transpose of V, or simply the transpose of V if V is real) is an n×n real or complex unitary matrix.

Comment: That is correct. Your point?

Comment: Im having a trouble understanding why V was to be also a orthonormal matrix. I didn't get why we need this stronger statement - to both matrices to be orthonormal.

Comment: Are you asking why is it useful that we can take $U$ and $V$ as unitary matrices?

Comment: Could you change your system so that $Av=ud$ and $A'u=dv$? Then your derivation will not have a jump inside. -- I would think that the orthonormality of V follows if you set U orthonormal, and vice versa. This perhaps requires that no singular value is zero.

Comment: i stated from the equations (of the definition of singular value)

Comment: Thanks @LutzL: what means having a jump inside? we cannot (if m!=n) swap u with v as it belongs to A space.
  If not wrong, singular values d are taken from AA' u = Av d = u d^2 and A'Av = Aud = v d^2 (that is, the roots of the eigenvalues of AA'/A'A) and by convention those are ordered by magnitude in D diagonal following the same order for the respective vectors in both U and V matrices.

Comment: You go from $AUU'=VDU'$ to $A=UDV'$. You should also take care where you change from the consideration of single singular vectors to the matrices of the singular vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one uses the symmetric system $AV=UD$, $A'U=VD$ and assumes that $U'U=I$ is chosen, then $V'VD=V'A'U=D'U'U=D'$. Under the assumption that $D$ is invertible, and all matrices are square the orthogonality of $V$ follows.

If one of the assumption fails, the full orthogonality, resp. the orthonormality of the columns of $V$ is not required. But it helps numerical stability, and the standard algorithm for the SVD splits of rotation or reflection factors and collects them in U and V, so that $U$ and $V$ are orthogonal (isometric) by construction.

Comment: So after transposing AV=UD, V'A' = D'U' we get V'A'U=D'U'U <=> V'V D = D'U'U = D', implying that V'V is also identity if D'=D and D is a square diagonal so i supose is ok. Thanks @LutzL!